# IntelliJ IDEA 14: How to skip tests while deploying project into Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a [Spring MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Model-view-controller_framework) project using [IntelliJ IDEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) 14 as my IDE (I'm new to IntelliJ IDEA; I used [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29)).

My main Java code is in folder `src/main`, and the unit test code is in `src/test`. While deploying the project, I found that all the unit tests are executed.

How can I skip all the unit tests while deploying the project into Tomcat?

Comment: are you using maven?

Comment: yes, i'm using maven. @albert

Comment: could that help? http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html

Comment: what i have guessed too, but then its not a specific intellij question.
http://maven.apache.org/general.html#skip-test

Answer (score 128, accepted):

In case you are using `Maven`, on the `View` > `Tool Windows` > `Maven Projects` click on the button shown below ( called `Skip Tests Mode`). Essentially it is taking the `test` phase out of the lifecycle when you say run `package`.

[image]

Comment: Does an option exist to do this on a per project basis?  If you click Skip Tests Mode, test runs are disabled for all maven projects.

Comment: This didn't work me (or at least the way I want it to). Even after disabling tests like this, when I run a Run or Debug configuration, the build attempts to compile the tests. Can we skip compile as well? Because in the codebase I'm working there are hell lot of tests with compile errors.

Comment: How to skip even building the tests/test packages?

Comment: Still works in IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.2 (Community Edition), the icon has changed though.

Answer (score 13):

When creating a maven configuration for the project. On the ***Runner tab*** you can click on skip test checkbox as below :

[image]

It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Even I faced this same issue as I have newly started using IntelliJ starting today. So I have trouble to find that logo in the screenshot shared in the post shared by `dimitrisli` and also accepted answer. Let me share my solution to this issue with latest IntelliJ version.

Open IntelliJ IDE, press `Ctrl + Alt + S`, this will open settings window, now look at the screenshot I shared and do the same settings and you are done. Make sure you click the check box for `Skip Tests`.

My IntelliJ IDE version:
`IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.4 (Community Edition)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Tomcat Run/Debug configurations you can specify in the *Before launch* section a maven task with this parameter:

`-Dmaven.test.skip=true`

Answer (score 1):

Toggle 'Skip Tests' Mode.

This button will help you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

mvn -DskipTests=true clean install (or other command)

Answer (score 0):

Edit Run configuration > Java Options and Modify > Select "Skip tests" and Save

[image: Maven Run/Debug Configuration]